# Storing Directory hierarchy in Datastructure Qt

Tags: c++, qt

How should i store data which is going into a TreeView? A Dictionary (`QHash`)? Plain Text? JSON?

My Hierarchy would be something like:

```
{
    'Cloth': {
        'Tissue':None,
        'Leather': {
            'Bandage': None
        }
        },

    'Smoke': {
        'White':{
            'Smallscale': None,
            'Largescale':None
        }
    }
}
```

**Actions:**

When I click a leaf-Element it will retrieve the Fullpath, like **"Smoke/White/Smallscale"** and this will be used as a key to place a SQL-Query.

I would use **QStandardItem** for every entry and when clicked, I would recursively call their parents, till I hit root.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [QJsonTreeWidget](https://github.com/valerino/QJsonTreeWidget)?

Of course you don't need to use that library, but I do think you should use JSON in any case. It's almost a standard nowadays and very useful when we're working with trees.

Boost also has a wonderful library to work with [JSON](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser).

Comment: Seriously, i don't want to be dependent on any external library. it is a tiny thing and most of the C++ Libraries somehow have bad support for JSON. Actually i think know of just iterating and parsing QHash.

Comment: Well, in your case I would prefer JSON to `QHash`. I have no problem in using boost in any C++ project. It's almost a standard in C++ and it's open source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the json library (like cajun) to parse json file.

This is the Qt part:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QTreeView>

class SimpleTreeView :public QTreeView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
        SimpleTreeView(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void slot_item_clicked(const QModelIndex &idx);

private:
         QStandardItemModel *model;
};

#include <simpletreeview.h>
#include <qmessagebox.h>
#include <qobject.h>

SimpleTreeView::SimpleTreeView(QWidget *parent) : QTreeView(parent)
{
        model = new QStandardItemModel(2,1);
        QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem("Cloth");

        QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem("Smoke");

        model->setItem(0, 0, item1);
        model->setItem(1, 0, item2);

        QStandardItem *item3 = new QStandardItem("White");
        item2->appendRow(item3);

        QStandardItem *leaf = new QStandardItem("Smallscale");
        leaf->setData("Smoke/White/Smallscale");
        item3->appendRow(leaf);
        setModel(model);

        connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT(slot_item_clicked(const QModelIndex &)));
}

void SimpleTreeView::slot_item_clicked(const QModelIndex & idx)
{
    QString strData = model->itemFromIndex(idx)->data().toString();
    QMessageBox::information(NULL, "Title", strData, QMessageBox::Yes, QMessageBox::Yes);
}

// main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <simpletreeview.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    SimpleTreeView view;
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't ask for an example, Qt has already tons of example including the Treeview. I asked more about methods how others are using this widget and how they prepare the data.